# Selecting a dictionary key value from a SQL table column which contains dictionaries in each row

Tags: sql, dictionary, key

I have a SQL table named `RESTAURANT` where there is a column named `PROFILE`. In each row, column `PROFILE` contains a dictionary as follows:

```
{
    'cuisine': None, 
    'id': 521693, 
    'img': None, 
    'prep_time': 5,
    'servings': 1, 
    'source_url': None,
    'summarize': 'Mango, Banana, Rasp...thie</a>.', 
    'title': 'Mango, Banana, Rasp... Smoothie',
    'very_healthy': None
}
```

I want to query the value of `cuisine` key from each row for the column `PROFILE`. How can I do it?

I tried the following:
`Select PROFILE['cuisine'] FROM RESTAURANT` but it gives error

Comment: What DBMS are you using?

Comment: MySQL, Presto are the two DBMS I have access to